# IndexOutOfRangeException in the Ajax.Net extensions framework

Tags: c#, ajax.net

For some reason when I attempt to make a request to an Ajax.net web service with the ScriptService attribute set, an exception occurs deep inside the protocol class which I have no control over. Anyone seen this before?

Here is the exact msg:
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerType..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext ontext, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest  request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)

thx 
Trev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also make sure your web.config is setup properly for asp.net ajax:

[http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/ConfiguringASPNETAJAX.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20080914214955/http://asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/ConfiguringASPNETAJAX.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

This is usually an exception while reading parameters into the web service method...are you sure you're passing the number/type of parameters the method is expecting?

Comment: Good Answer! More towards explaining real issue than cover-ups.